# Chmod recursively for /

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I was playing around with an old system and mainly trying to kill it in a strange manner.

What happens if I `chmod -R 0777 /` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much unless you're root. If you are root, services that require files with certain permissions will stop working. `sudo` is one of those.

Comment: Frankly speaking, this question doesn't belong here. It may better fit in UL. Anyways, you have a nice point up there..

Comment: For OP's reference, "UL" is the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

Comment: UL already has several questions about trying to recover from this ([here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems), and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/recovering-from-chmod-r-777-in-ubuntu)), as do serverfault ([here](http://serverfault.com/questions/498915/best-way-to-recover-mysql-from-a-chmod-r-777-with-databases-intact/499099), and the other questions it links to), and askubuntu ([here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc)).